# How do I calculate the number of years to target in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, forecasting

If I have an average YOY growth of say 2.5%, current year sales of $500,000, and target sales of $1,000,000. Is there a way to calculate the number of years until I hit my target (assuming a continued YOY growth rate of 2.5%), without calculating each additional years's sales on a different row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NPER` function for this:

```
=NPER(Growth,0,currentSales,-targetSales)
```

Note that this gives the same result as @Dominique, but is using a built-in Excel function.

Also, by virtue of the nature of Excel financial functions, the signs for the current and future Sales need to be different.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple formula for this:

```
Money_end = (1+r/100)^Y*Money_begin
```

Where:

```
Money_begin = the starting amount of money, in this case 500000.
Money_end   = the finishing amount of money, in this case 1000000.
r           = the percent ratio, in this case 2.5.
Y           = the amount of years, which you are looking for.
```

So, your question comes down to solving this equation:

```
1000000 = (1+2.5/100)^Y * 500000
2       = 1.025^Y

Y = log(2)/log(1.025)
```

If you want this to be solved by Excel, you might use the formula and use the `Solver` basic Excel feature for coming up with the same (but numerical instead of analytical) result.